# How to copy everything including logo to a workbook from a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a sheet from one `Workbook` to another using [vba](/questions/tagged/vba). I am using the following code:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice").Cells.Copy
```

When I run it only the cells get copied and logo isn't getting copied. How to I change this to copy the logo also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply copy the entire **sheet** rather than the `Cells`

Something like this to copy from the `Workbook` containing the code to the first sheet of *Book1*

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice").Copy Workbooks("Book1").Sheets(1)
```

Or from the `ActiveWorkbook`

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice").Copy Workbooks("Book1").Sheets(1)
```

Comment: Thanks @Brettdj I would like to open an existing workbook and paste the worksheet can you please help? My code is as below'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice").Cells.Copy
            Set oWkb = Workbooks.Open("D:\Invoices\" & str1 & " " & Format(str2, "mmm") & "-" & Format(str2, "YYYY") & " " & str3 & ".xlsx")

            oWkb.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial'

Comment: Got it @brettdj i used `Set oWkb = Workbooks.Open("D:\Invoices\" & str1 & " " & Format(str2, "mmm") & "-" & Format(str2, "YYYY") & " " & str3 & ".xlsx")
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice").Copy oWkb.Sheets(1)` Thank you very much!